# Is there any actual reaction between ferric chloride and CO2 gas?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I want to make Ferrous carbonates with Ferric chloride using $\ce{CO2}$. Does it even react with $\ce{CO2}$? how to know if it reacts to form $\ce{FeCO3}$?

Comment: The way to know it is to learn chemistry. Short of that, you will be left to wonder in the dark.

Comment: Does CO2 have reducing and alkaline properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Atomistry on Ferrous carbonate](http://iron.atomistry.com/ferrous_carbonate.html), to quote:

> In the laboratory ferrous carbonate may be obtained as a white precipitate by adding sodium carbonate to a solution of ferrous sulphate in the absence of air. If air is present, the precipitate rapidly turns green in consequence of oxidation, carbon dioxide is evolved, and ultimately the mass consists almost entirely of ferric hydroxide.

As such to prepare FeCO3, I would recommend adding your FeCl2 to aqueous Washing Soda (Na2CO3):

$\ce{FeCl2 + Na2CO3 (aq) -> 2 NaCl (aq) + FeCO3 (s) }$

Controlling air/oxygen exposure perhaps with a blanket of CO2 by performing the above reaction in a larger vessel filled with carbon dioxide may work.

So, you do still get to employ your CO2 in the preparation, but as a direct reaction path, it apparently is not.

[EDIT] Apparently, one can employ FeCl3 to create a transient  Ferric carbonate in the above scheme, as [per a reference](https://www.softschools.com/formulas/chemistry/iron_iii_carbonate_formula/670/), to quote:

> Physical properties of iron (III) has not been evaluated due to its instability and quickly decomposition. It is hygroscopic and decomposes in water.

So, employing an aqueous ferric salt, or allowing the oxidation of the ferrous, does not lend itself to the formation of a stable iron carbonate salt here.

Note, the action of Fe on FeCl3 absence oxygen exposure is a possible path to FeCl2:

$\ce{Fe + 2 FeCl3 <-> 3 FeCl2}$

Comment: Hmm, but the OP considers ferric chloride FeCl3, not more suitable ferrous chloride FeCl2, unless there is an error.

Comment: @poutnic Ferric or ferrous, anything that'll do, I just want to use CO2 gas I have with something to make something strong ;) such as ca(oh)2 + co2 --> caco3

Comment: By way of an [EDIT], I have addressed the reason for the use of the ferrous here.